# Spring log4j not able to save log file on osx

Tags: java, macos, spring, log4j

I've got a problem with spring log4j on osx, I can't save the log file... this is my configurations:

**log4.properties**

```
#log4j.properties

#LOGGER
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, APPENDER_OUT, APPENDER_FILE

#APPENDER_OUT
log4j.appender.APPENDER_OUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.APPENDER_OUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.APPENDER_OUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

#APPENDER_FILE
log4j.appender.APPENDER_FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.APPENDER_FILE.File=test.log
log4j.appender.APPENDER_FILE.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.APPENDER_FILE.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.APPENDER_FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.APPENDER_FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p [%C:%L] - %m%n
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.andreadorigo.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Webapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>



    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.spring.security.version>
        <org.slf4j.version>1.6.1</org.slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Webapp</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**console errors**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

To say the truth I can see those errors too:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Could they be in conflict?

Comment: Seems like your classpath is not set properly. Do you have all log4j and slf4j jars?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I get them like pom.xml
<properties>
 `code` <org.springframework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  <org.spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.spring.security.version>
  <org.slf4j.version>1.6.1</org.slf4j.version>
 </properties>

<dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.13</version>
  </dependency>
`code`

Comment: Please edit your question and add your pom.

Answer (score 1):

I see only `log4j` and `sl4j-api` jars in your pom. My guess is that in order to use `log4j` as `sl4j`'s implementation you need to add `slf4j-log4j12.jar`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

BTW, the [link from your logs](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) explains what happens: `sl4j-api` contains only [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) and it's no-op implementation. sl4j is modular by design and supports different logger implementations, that are shipped in their own jars.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, it was a log4j log file matter... I specified the correct osx path...
There is a thing I don't get... how should I set the log file path when I deploy it on a real web server?

Comment: When you deploy on real server, your app will have access to some predefined properties. E.g. `catalina.home` for Tomcat or `jboss.server.home.dir` for JBoss. And you use them in placeholders in config: `<param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/myapp/log.txt"/>`